# Virtual function overloading

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

Lets say that we have :

```
Class A
{
public:
   virtual void print(){ std::cout<<" A "<<endl; }
}

Class B : public A
{
public:
   virtual void print(int x){ std::cout<<" B "<<endl;}

}
```

I thought that the definition in Class B of function print will hide the function print from class A. But the following code works and prints " A "

```
int main()
{

A * a = new B;

a->print();

return 0;
}
```

If I write the main function like this it doesnt work :

```
int main()
{

B b;

b.print();

return 0;
}
```

What i Want to know is...in my first main() example I have a B object that calls print()...shouldnt then print()  be hidden and have an error like in the second main() example

Comment: You have a pointer to `A`, so you get `A`'s interface.

Comment: but i have a B object and the function is virtual...

Comment: Overloading is taking place here because the method signature is different. You *are not* overridding the same virtual function.

Comment: But you are accessing that object via `A`'s public interface.

Comment: @juanchopanza Wrong. `a` is a `B`, with `B`'s vtable. The problem is that `B`'s print doesn't override `A`'s because of the signature.

Comment: @anthony-arnold That doesn't mean I am wrong (which I am not). You cannot access a mathod that is not part of `A`'s interface via an `A` pointer. OP is aware that `B::print` hides `A::print`, they want to understand why they can still access `A::print` when they have instantiated a `B` object.

Comment: I know that i am not overriding...my question is why the code works because I am having a B object so the print() function from A  should be hidden

Comment: @user2896153: Hope you find it useful, *Note: nothing gets hidden when you have a base-pointer. Think about it: what a derived class does or does not do is irrelevant when the compiler is dealing with a base-pointer. The compiler might not even know that the particular derived class exists. Even if it knows of the existence of some particular derived class, it cannot assume that a specific base-pointer necessarily points at an object of that particular derived class....* [from here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html)

Comment: @greatwolf - there is no overloading here. `A` has **one** member function named `print`; it takes no arguments and returns `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is name lookup. In a call like `A *a = new B; a->print()` the compiler looks at the type of `a`, which is `A*`, and looks in the class `A` for a member function named `print`. It finds it and it calls it. Similarly, with `B *b = new B; b->print();` the compiler looks in class `B` for a member function named `print`; it finds `print(int)`, which can't be called with no arguments. And because it found a function named `print` in `B` it stops looking; it doesn't go into `A` to find `A::print()`. That's name hiding.

The key here is that name lookup starts with the declared type of the object; in these two examples the types are `A*` and `B*`, respectively. Lookup does **not** pay attention to the actual type of the thing that a pointer or reference points to or refers to.

Comment: Finally someone who understood the question and gave a nice answer...thank you very much :)

Answer (score 7):

The member function `print()` in `B` is not overriding the `print()` in `A` because it has a different signature. Therefore, when calling `print()` in your first, unedited version of `main()`, there is only one matching function to call, as pointed out by user  juanchopanza: `A::print()`.

EDIT: To summarize:

- **Polymorphic behavior**: If `A::print()` and `B::print()` had the same signature, the appropriate `print()` would be chosen at runtime as long as you reference the object through pointers or references.
- **Function overloading**: Since a class is a scope and functions do not overload across scopes, the functions from base classes are hidden by functions of the same name in a derived class. For this, the **type of the variable** you are using to refer to your object is the one that matters, **not the type of the object itself**. Therefore, in your second example you get an error that there is no matching function to call, but in your first example, only one function is in scope.

Comment: There is no "best match", you can only call `print()` via `A`'s interface, and you can only call `print(int)` via `B`'s interface.

Comment: @juanchopanza: you are right, thank you, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is because two `print()` functions have different signatures. Two functions - `print()` and `print(int)` are considered different and cannot be <s>overloaded</s> overridden by each other.

Comment: They do not **overload** because they are defined in different scopes. The difference in signatures is the reason that `B::print` does not **override** `A::print`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, of course. These two words are too similar for a non-native :)

Comment: They do look alike, don't they? `<g>`

Answer (score 1):

Named overloading functions in a derived class *are* hiding those from the base class. However, you'll need to use the derived class interface to see so:

```
B b;
b.print(); // won't work
```

Comment: I know this...but if i am using a B object calling a a virtual function ... what is happening in this case ?

Comment: Why would `b.print()` not work? `B` inherits `A`'s `print()` function just fine. It'll still print "A" though.

Comment: @arne because `B::print` hides `A::print`.

Comment: @user2896153: You mean using `A& a = b; b.print();`? Since you haven't overridden `print()` (the version without parameters) it would call the base class version. If you override `print()` in `B` it would, of course, call that version.

Comment: It inherits it but the access is shadowed by B's print(int) function. You may use `b.A::print()` if you really want... but it looks a bit ridiculous.

Comment: @arne: The root of the question is about name hiding: the function `A::print()` is hidden by the overload `B::print(int)`. If you wanted to call `A::print()` you'd need to use `b.A::print()`.

Comment: What i Wanted to know is...in my first main() example I have a B object that calls print()...shouldnt then print be hidden like in the second main example

Answer (score 0):

Check your class definitions; the print functions in `A` and `B` have different signatures. When you call

```
a->print();
```

There's only one function that fits that signature, which is `A::print()`. If you remove the `int` parameter from `B`'s definition you should observe the behaviour you're expecting.